# Maven with docker - lookup docker on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins

Context: I am following [this tutorial](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/#fork-sample-repository) under Windows 10 and stuck at "Create your initial Pipeline as a Jenkinsfile".

The jenkins file downloads the maven:3.9.0-eclipse-temurin-11 Docker image and runs this image as a separate container, but when I tried to build on the pipeline, I got returned error

```
error during connect: Get "https://docker:2376/v1.24/containers/maven:3.9.0-eclipse-temurin-11/json": dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
```

The pipeline looks like this:

[image]

I tried to click the link in the error, it gives

[image]

As I didn't find maven:3.9.0-eclipse-temurin-11 on Docker Hub, I tried with other listed versions like 3.9.2-eclipse-temurin-11-alpine, but the error is the same.

Ideally the build should succeed.

Comment: Try with linux. Windows is not for devops.

Comment: Based on this https://hub.docker.com/r/csanchez/maven/tags?page=1&name=eclipse-temurin-11 your assumption is not accurate... furthermore the output shows that the access url `https://docker..` seemed to be not correct...that means either configuration/proxy/firewall etc. are not correct??